# Creating array of struct instances [C]

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm creating a finite state machine for an embedded systems lab. The compiler (I'm using ARM's Kiel) is complaining on my try to declare an array of instances of a struct. What have I done wrong?

My code (part of):

```
struct State {
    unsigned long OutCars;
    unsigned long OutWalk;
    unsigned long Time;
    unsigned long Next[8];
};

typedef const struct State SType;


SType FSM[11] = {
    {0x0C, PF1, 100, {goW, goW, waitW, waitW, waitW, waitW, waitW, waitW} },
    {0x14, PF1, 50,  {goW, goW, goS, goS, goWa, goWa, goWa, goWa} },
    {0x21, PF1, 100, {goS, waitS, goS, waitS, waitS, waitS, waitS, waitS} },
    {0x22, PF1, 50,  {goS, goW, goS, goW, goWa, goW, goWa, goW} },
    {0x24, PF3, 100, {goWa, off1, off1, off1, goWa, off1, off1, off1} },
    {0x24, OFF, 50,  {on1, on1, on1, on1, on1, on1, on1, on1} },
    {0x24, PF1, 50,  {off2, off2, off2, off2, off2, off2, off2, off2} },
    {0x24, OFF, 50,  {on2, on2, on2, on2, on2, on2, on2, on2} },
    {0x24, PF1, 50,  {off3, off3, off3, off3, off3, off3, off3, off3} },
    {0x24, OFF, 50,  {on3, on3, on3, on3, on3, on3, on3, on3} },
    {0x24, PF1, 50,  {goWa, goW, goS, goS, goWa, goW, goS, goS} },   
};
```

The error message:

> ...
>
> TableTrafficLight.c(155): error:  #67: expected a "}"
>
> {0x0C, PF1, 100, {goW, goW, waitW, waitW, waitW, waitW, waitW, waitW} },
>
> ...

**Edit: Turns out I've ended my `#define` statements with semicolons. Oops. Lesson learned.**

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code that you've shown. (Of course, you haven't shown how you defined all those constants.) I suggest putting that code, and the associated definitions in a separate file, and try compiling that file by itself. Often, error messages issued by C compilers are caused by errors (e.g. missing semicolons) earlier in the file.

Comment: Compiler rrrors/warnings refer to a specific line of source (155 here). You should always make clear which line this is.

Comment: @alk The line shown under the error message appears to be the first line of the array initializer.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you! Maybe this is my way forward. I'll look into the adjacent code.

Comment: @alk Good point, I'll keep that in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 2):

Remove last comma before closing brace (remove as highlighted):

```
SType FSM[11] = {
    {0x0C, PF1, 100, {goW, goW, waitW, waitW, waitW, waitW, waitW, waitW} },
    {0x14, PF1, 50,  {goW, goW, goS, goS, goWa, goWa, goWa, goWa} },
    {0x21, PF1, 100, {goS, waitS, goS, waitS, waitS, waitS, waitS, waitS} },
    {0x22, PF1, 50,  {goS, goW, goS, goW, goWa, goW, goWa, goW} },
    {0x24, PF3, 100, {goWa, off1, off1, off1, goWa, off1, off1, off1} },
    {0x24, OFF, 50,  {on1, on1, on1, on1, on1, on1, on1, on1} },
    {0x24, PF1, 50,  {off2, off2, off2, off2, off2, off2, off2, off2} },
    {0x24, OFF, 50,  {on2, on2, on2, on2, on2, on2, on2, on2} },
    {0x24, PF1, 50,  {off3, off3, off3, off3, off3, off3, off3, off3} },
    {0x24, OFF, 50,  {on3, on3, on3, on3, on3, on3, on3, on3} },
    {0x24, PF1, 50,  {goWa, goW, goS, goS, goWa, goW, goS, goS} }, //remove this comma  
};
```

becomes:

```
SType FSM[11] = {
    {0x0C, PF1, 100, {goW, goW, waitW, waitW, waitW, waitW, waitW, waitW} },
    {0x14, PF1, 50,  {goW, goW, goS, goS, goWa, goWa, goWa, goWa} },
    {0x21, PF1, 100, {goS, waitS, goS, waitS, waitS, waitS, waitS, waitS} },
    {0x22, PF1, 50,  {goS, goW, goS, goW, goWa, goW, goWa, goW} },
    {0x24, PF3, 100, {goWa, off1, off1, off1, goWa, off1, off1, off1} },
    {0x24, OFF, 50,  {on1, on1, on1, on1, on1, on1, on1, on1} },
    {0x24, PF1, 50,  {off2, off2, off2, off2, off2, off2, off2, off2} },
    {0x24, OFF, 50,  {on2, on2, on2, on2, on2, on2, on2, on2} },
    {0x24, PF1, 50,  {off3, off3, off3, off3, off3, off3, off3, off3} },
    {0x24, OFF, 50,  {on3, on3, on3, on3, on3, on3, on3, on3} },
    {0x24, PF1, 50,  {goWa, goW, goS, goS, goWa, goW, goS, goS} } 
};
```

Comment: Umm, NO. The C specification specifically allows that comma.

Comment: @user3386109: "*allows that comma.*" From C99 on only.

Comment: Tried, but his had now effect. Also, the compiler had nothing bad to say about it. Thanks for pointing out though, it could have been the issue.

Comment: ANSI C has always allowed (infact, demanded that final comma) other versions of C have that final comma as optional

Comment: this answer is incorrect.  (the posted question fails to disclose the definitions of PF`, OFF, ....) the posted code is correct, so the problem lies elsewhere